# Fastest way to draw one million pixels in openGL 4?

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics

I started using opengl and I was wondering how I could put over 1 million pixels on the screen without getting under 10 fps. Currently I have set up a std::vector that takes in each pixel information during the update stage of the main loop then afterwards before it renders.
The render stage looks like this:
`glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*data.size(),
        &data[0], GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);`
then I `glDrawArrays`

Each pixel takes color and 2d position. Is there a faster method of drawing one million pixels? I use dynamic draw because I want changing colors on the screen while each individual pixel gives random colors. Sort of like a tv on a broken channel.

Comment: 1 million pixels is roughly 1024x1024, what about a textured quad?

Comment: instead of sending that data through a vector.. can't it be calculated in a fragment shader. that would be fastest way !

Comment: that's what I was aiming at, draw one quad and calculate the texture information in the fragment shader...

Comment: I am in the beginning of my opengl programmers guide book, looks like i have to read some more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't store the colors in an array but instead calculate them in the fragment shader.

You create a noise texture and use wrapping for its sampler. You should also pass in a few uniforms that change each frame and combine them in a non-linear way with the window coordinates.

Comment: Can I have two different GL_TEXTURE_2D's to copy info to? How do i gain access to a new different buffer? Am I supposed to make a new vbo?

Comment: @user2893243 you won't be using a VBO but instead textures exclusively (at most you will have 4 vertices to create a full screen quad), but yes you can have more textures and uniforms to base your noise on

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if I didnt use textures, how could i fix the problem of the pixels spacing out more and more as i resize the window to become bigger

Comment: you mean the pixels just zooming out? you should use some high frequency trig functions (position.x*5000) to add some high frequency noise in the output